# How to execute PostgreSQL query in Django

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to fetch the PostgreSQL table onto HTML using Django, When I execute the spatial query in the query Tool of PostgreSQL I got the perfect results, but When I'm trying to execute the same script from Django getting all rows of data. Thank you for helping in advance.

```
SQL query which is working perfectly

SELECT *
    FROM jhk_schls as point,jhk_urban as polygon
WHERE ST_Within(point.geom, polygon.geom)
```

Django Script

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        first_layer = request.POST.get('first_layer')
        spati_func = request.POST.get('spa_func')
        second_layer = request.POST.get('secon_layer')
        within_fun = 'select * from' + " " + str(first_layer) + " " + 'as point,' + str(second_layer) + " " + 'as polygon' + " " + 'WHERE' + " " + str(spati_func)+'(point.geom, polygon.geom)'
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(within_fun)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return render(request, 'geoit/search.html',{ 'data':data})
    return render(request,'geoit/search.html')
```

HTML

````
<span>Select Layer</span>
      <select name="first_layer">
     <option value="-1" disabled  selected >Please select</option>
     Layer<li><option value="jhk_schls">jhk_schls</option></li>
    </select>
  </br>
  <span>Spatial Functions</span>
<select name="spa_func">
     <option value="-1" disabled  selected >Please select</option>
     Layer<li><option value="ST_Within">ST_Within</option></li>
    </select>
</br>
<span>Select Layer</span>
<select name="secon_layer">

     <option value="-1" disabled  selected >Please select</option>
     Layer<li><option value="jhk_urban">jhk_urban</option></li>
     
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
          </p>
        </div>
</form>
            <button type="submit" value="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
        <p></p>
        <center>
            <table>
    
           
        {% for item in data %}
                  <tr>
                <td>{{ item.0 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.2 }}</td>
                 
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
        </center>
```
````

Comment: Two very important things: in Django you don't use SQL, you the ORM instead and if you have to use SQL in other situations you never construct it with string concatenations.  It would lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Did you take the Django [tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/)?

Comment: Could you please provide any tutorials to solve the problem? otherwise, provide any similar projects. I'm intermediate to Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django you would want to use the Django ORM to get data out of your database.

In this case, please look at the 'within' function of geoquerysets:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#within

As a side note, the way you constucted the query in your view, passing parameters from the view directly into your query, opens you up for SQL injection attacks and can be quite dangerous. *IF* you would need to create SQL with input from query string parameters, please read up on how to do this safely: https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/#passing-safe-query-parameters